# Enter to synchronized function by FIFO

Tags: java

I'm developing synchronized function that might be entered from different threads. I need to make mechanism that allows enter to my function according FIFO method in case when several threads are calling it. What is the way of solving this task in Java 1.4 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use fair locking.  In Java 5.0 you can use `new ReentrantLock(true);` to make it a fair lock.

In Java 1.4 you can try the old Concurrency library by Doug Lea.
http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/classes/EDU/oswego/cs/dl/util/concurrent/QueuedSemaphore.html

I am amazed anyone still develops in Java 1.4.  There are kids developing in Java who weren't born when this version was released.